# How can I control which URL <t:pagelink> renders?

Tags: tapestry

### Background

Tapestry's pagelink component shortens the logical name of a page to a nice and handy URL.

For example (found in the [Tapestry Documentation](https://tapestry.apache.org/page-navigation.html#PageNavigation-Contents%7CRelatedArticlesLogicalPageNameShortening)), if the page class is `org.example.pages.address.CreateAddress`, the URL rendered by pagelink renders a link to `https://<host>/address/create`. That is, the redundant "Address" is removed as a suffix.

### Problem

I really like this feature, yet it causes a problem when the page class name contains the name of a sub-package.

For example, `org.example.pages.member.MembershipProfile` results in `https://<host>/member/shipprofile`. The link works but the URL looks scilly and not carefully designed.

Is there a way to configure this behavior, like defining exceptions somehow, to get the URL to be `https://<host>/member/membershipprofile`?

### Workaround

As a workaround, one can code plain HTML like so `<a href="https://<host>/member/membershipprofile">...</a>`. This works, but is less convenient, especially when including context.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change this behaviour without overriding core services.

You could also rename `MembershipProfile` to `Profile`, or use http://www.tynamo.org/tapestry-routing+guide/ to provide custom URL mappings if rename is not an option.

Comment: I didn't want another dependency just for that, hence went with your suggestion to just rename the page. Thanks for your help.